# Storing an API Call email in a variable

Tags: facebook-graph-api, scope, user-permissions

I'm having trouble storing the user's email address in a variable in javascript. What I want to do is call the API, get the email address, and store it in the "email" variable, for use in other functions on the screen.

My code looks like this:

```
function emailCheck(){
    var email;
    FB.api('/me',email = function(response){
        return response.email;
        })
    }

    alert(email);
```

I did check to make sure that I have the proper permissions. I would put `alert(response.email)` in my response section, and it would alert with the proper email. The problem is that I cant get the email variable accessible **outside** of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a continuation as all API methods are asynchronous

```
function emailCheck(continuation){
  FB.api('/me', function(response){
    continuation(response && response.email);
  });
}

emailCheck(function(email) {
  alert(email);
}
```

A different way is to use Promises, Futures or deferreds (same thing really) to abstract pieces of this.

Comment: Ah, good catch on the async part. Been a while since i've built with the JS SDK. Deleted my answer and endorsed this one.

Comment: okay, I cant seem to get this to work. I would use `email = emailcheck(function(email){alert(email);}` and I'm still getting 'undefined'

Comment: @RickeyESmith - async methods cannot return data - they have to take a callback as I've shown in the sample, a continuation.